# How can I add calendar on edit mood for different row in DHTMLX Grid

Tags: calendar, grid, dhtml

I am working on DHTMLX grid where in my grid the different row have different type of data. And I have provided the facility for a each row to edit the values. There are two rows, one it name of the item another is value for that item. So there is different type of values like price[number], title[string], status [drop down option list], created[date] etc. so I see there is an option for defining the grid's row type for each. Everything is working properly but the calendar is not showing.

Can anyone help me on this?

I have used row type for calendar is "dhxCalendar" but getting error as after that no row is showing up and the design gone missing. Any kind of help will be appriciable.

Answer (score 0):

a) be sure to include related files

- excell/dhtmlxgrid_excell_dhxCalendar.js
- dhxCalendar/codebase/dhtmlxcalendar.js

b) be sure that format of date in you datasource (xml|json) is the default one (d/m/y), or you are using setDateFormat as

```
grid.setDateFormat("format to show", "format in datasource");
```